# Javascript 'clicking' a button

Tags: javascript, class, button, input, click

I read that you cannot click a button if it's a submit/form so I've been trying to 'click' an image button in a webpage however I'm always getting an error (null).

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return logInTBLocal();" value="Login" tabindex="11">
```

How do I 'click' this button with only the above that is given?

Comment: is the function `logInTBLocal` defined... ?!

Comment: don't think it has to be defined , i just don't know what to code to make the button get clicked ; basically there is an image button and i want to click it using JS like you'd click a standard button

Comment: Yout should learn javascript and HTML first. **Is it for homework?**

Comment: You can click any buttons whether in a form or not. Why do need an the "return" statement in the onclick? That is usually more useful in the onsubmit method on the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can't click the submit button, but what you can do is:

```
document.getElementById('myFormId').submit();
```

Comment: No it's just a personal project of mine + I don't really have the time to learn JS properly however I find it extremeley easy prior to me knowing another language fluently so generally the syntax and style is quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing the point of your own question.  Let me help clarify, if I misunderstood you then I apologize in advance.

You can click the 'button' you created.  But, you have to define **logInTBLocal()**.  When you submit your form, or click this button the 'onclick' event handler is going to call logInTBLocal().  If this function is not defined, you'll receive an error.

Here is an Example,

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function logInTBLocal() {
      alert("Sams Teach yourself JavaScript in 24 Hours would help!");
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Hopefully this will point you in the right Direction.